# Add button inside tooltip Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tooltip

I am trying to make a custom tool-tip which contains buttons inside it, these buttons when clicked will display more information in the tool-tip or redirect you to another website, something like the image below:
[image]

The code i am using to generate the tool-tip in chart.js:

```
const chart = new Chart(html_object,{
.....
  options : {
     tooltips : {
         enabled : false,
         custom : (tooltipModel) => {
           //code to generate custom tooltip
         }
     }
}
.....
})
```

i can put buttons inside the tool-tip using the code above, but when i hover over a dot in my line chart the tool-tip opens but when i stop hovering over the dot, the tool-tip disappears.

How can i fix this so that when i hover over the tool-tip it won't disappear?